# How to setup TC Server Developer Edition (in STS) and accessing a UNC path

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite, tcserver

I Have a java project running in Spring Tool Source IDE in an instance of TC Server Developer Edition and I need to access a UNC path share on our network.

How do I configure the TC Server Developer Edition to use our "Service Account" that has been granted access to the share on our network?

I read that for Apache Tomcat you could just configure the windows service, but the dev version of TC Server I have, it does not seem to have a service installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my own research, all I've been able to discover is that if the user has access to the UNC share, the dev ed. of TC Server has that access as well.  So, whatever user the STS IDE was started under, the TC Server will have the same access.

Answer (score 1):

TC Server Developer Edition can be easily installed as a service.
Go to you instance directory and type
 **tcruntime-ctl.bat install.**

I.e.

```
#>cd C:\dev\runtimes\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0\my-instance\bin
#>tcruntime-ctl.bat install
    Derived instance name:  my-instance
    Installing instance at C:\dev\runtimes\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0\my-instance
    wrapper  | VMware vFabric tc Runtime instance - tcruntime-C-dev-runtimes-vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.7.0-my-instance installed.
```

The output above will give you the name of the installed service.
Locate it in the windows services.Switch to Log On Tab and set up the account for the service.
[image: ,]